# Density function of $X + Y$, two i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

I've come across this sort of exercises a few times now and I always feel so unsure about how to solve them. This is one example:

Determine the density function of $X + Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d random variables in $[-1,1]$.

This is my solution so far:

$f_X(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$ for $x$ that belongs to $[-1,1],$
$f_Y(y) = -\frac{1}{2}$ for $y$ that belongs to $[-1,1]$

$P(X+Y \leq u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(y) dxdy \Rightarrow$

$f_{X+Y}(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(u-y) f_Y(y) dy $

$X + Y$ belongs to $[-2, 2]$

Now, after this, I'm lost. I don't know what the limits of the integral should be, and this is where I always have problems when doing this kind of exercise. The solution manual says to put it as $\int_{u-1}^{1} \frac{1}{4} dy$, I don't "see" it.

Comment: Excellent motivation to write down the densities fully, that is, mentioning the limits of their support. Here, the formulas for the densities, **valid for every real number $x$**, are $$f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=\tfrac12\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(x)=\tfrac12\mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant x\leqslant1},$$ hence $$f_{X+Y}(u)=\int_\mathbb R\tfrac14\mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant x\leqslant1}\mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant u-x\leqslant1}dx=\int_\mathbb R\tfrac14\mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant x\leqslant1}\mathbf 1_{u-1\leqslant x\leqslant u+1}dx.$$ Can you conclude?

Comment: Well, not completely. I think I understand that it has to be the intersection of the intervals $[-1,1]$ and $[u-1, u+1]$. In the solution manual, as I mentioned, they gave the lower limit $u-1$ and the upper limit $1$. Could they have chosen the lower limit as $-1$ and the upper as $u+1$? I still don't quite understand why they chose those specific limits.

Comment: Draw a figure will always help, in your case, draw a 2-dimension figure, where (X,Y) are equally likely to be in are rectangle bounded from -1 to 1. And $x+y<C$ is just a line.

Comment: Not interested in (what you reproduce from) the proof in your book. What matters is the length of the interval $[-1,1]\cap[u-1,u+1]$, whose formula obviously changes when $u-1$ or $u+1$ passes by $-1$ or $+1$. Thus the transitions occur at $u=-2$ (when $u+1=-1$),, $u=0$ (when $u-1=-1$ and $u+1=1$) and $u=2$ (when $u-1=1$). A semi-careful examination should allow you to complete the solution.

Comment: I believe I get it now. Thank you, and thanks to @RushengZhang , drawing a figure did help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $P(X+Y \leq u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(y) dxdy $ is wrong. The integral must be done inside an area that depends on $u$, where $X+Y\le u$ holds (pink region in the graphic)

[image]

In the range $0<u<1$ it's a little easier to compute the complementary probability (green zone). The integral is

$$P(X+Y \ge u)=\int_{Green} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy = \int_{Green} \frac 12 \frac 12dx dy = \frac14 Area_{Green}=\frac14 \frac{(2-u)^2}{2}$$

I think you can go on from here.